# How to deactivate a comand for a guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command(self, ctx):

    with open(env["JSON_DIR"] + "servers.json", "r") as f:
        s = json.load(f)
    if not ctx.message.content == f"{ctx.prefix}verify":
        if str(ctx.guild.id) in s:
            command = self.bot.get_command(ctx.message.content.split(f"{ctx.prefix}")[1])
            print(command)
            command.update(enabled=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="No estais verificados", description="Para poder verificar el server poner `$verify`", color=0x00fbff))
        else:
            command = self.bot.get_command(ctx.message.content.split(f"{ctx.prefix}")[1])
            command.update(enabled=True)
```

I want so that if the server is not verified the command that was executed to no be executed.

I have tried with `command.update()` but it doesn't really seem to work

Please help...